# How to fix unable to run Flutter app from VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I was using VSCode and Flutter without any problem in my Ubuntu machine.

Recently, I installed Mircosoft .Net core in my machine.

Later when I try to run a Flutter application by pressing `F5`, it is trying to download `C#`.

I'm unable to run Flutter application from VSCode, where as I can run the app from console using the `flutter run` command.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is a bug in VSCode. It works after downloading, C# package. It is kind of high-volume btw.